# Show opened file location in Windows Paint

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-paint

How to show the location of actually opened file in Windows 10 Paint?

I'm using print screen plugin that opens print screens in paint. I've found out I have no idea where the opened file is located and I wasn't able to figure out how to show the path in the program...

It is certainly not under File->Properties.

Comment: @Akina I just tried that, but Save As always goes to the default Pictures folder in my profile.

Comment: SaveAs saves to last folder you've saved into...

Comment: Click "File". On the right pane (Last files) move mouse pointer over the filename (usually number 1). Wait 1 sec - the tooltip with full pathname will occur.

Comment: @Akina, perhaps you could post that tooltip trick as an anwer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click "File".

On the right pane (Last files) move mouse pointer over the filename (usually number 1).

Wait 1 sec - the tooltip with full pathname will occur.

Comment: Great! This is it!

Answer (score 0):

That information does not seem to be available.

As a workaround, you could make a small modification to the image (and then undo that change), then close Paint. It will show a message asking if you want to save changes to [Full name].

However, long filenames will be truncated to fit the messagebox. In that case, you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the message text, and paste it in Notepad, for instance.

Comment: Hmm it also doesn't seem to work, it ask me if I want to save changes to ...\2019_05_21_(...)

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo I see, long names are truncated. But a copy of that messagebox (Ctrl+C), will contain the full path.

Comment: Wow, that is the trick!